# Gaussian Process Confidence vs Credible Intervals

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, confidence-interval, credible-interval

Since Gaussian Process returns a [distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55831318/7066507) and not a point estimate, why this [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_noisy_targets.html) (and actually in every example with GP) talk about Confidence Intervals on the analogues for Bayesian statistics the Credible Intervals?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. A confidence interval is a distribution.

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci Confidence intervals are point estimates and they differ from the Credible intervals (where you can talk about probabilities) 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval

Comment: I have to disagree with this, confidence intervals are intervals computed from your data. I think, this clarification would be more suited on cross validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering about that, too. My assumption is the following: `GaussianProcessRegressor` from `sklearn` implements Algorithm 2.1 from Rasmussen & Williams (2006). Throughout this book, the ±2σ interval around µ is referred to as "95% confidence region". They simply do not make a distinction between "confidence" and "credible" region. I think the authors of `sklearn` adopted that.

C. E. Rasmussen & C. K. I. Williams, Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning, MIT Press, 2006